# Change cursor back to auto after unload

Tags: javascript, html

I am editing a page that was created by somebody else. And this page has the `onbeforeunload` value set for `body` that calls for a function which changes the cursor to wait. So when a user clicks on a button, it displays the wait cursor, but if a user clicks cancel right afterwards, the cursor remains being `wait`. How do I make it go back to auto/default?

The body tag code:

```
<body onbeforeunload="showHourglass();">
```

JS function

```
function showHourglass() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
        }
```

Comment: By cancel, do you mean the browsers stop button?

Comment: I should probably clarify that this problem only occurs when user clicks on the download button which starts a file download, but if they select not to download a file (click cancel), it goes back to the page, and the cursor is still waiting.

Comment: How does the cursor get set back to default when the user doesn't click cancel?  Is this a callback that fires when the download is complete?  Or, does a postback just refresh the page so state is reset?

Comment: then do a onload on the page and set the cursor to "default"

Comment: Personally, I would avoid the problem alltogether and just use `window.open(resourcePath)` to get the file.  This way the browser opens up a new tab and handles the loading visual indicators all on its own.  If necessary, you could redirect the user to `landingPage` after making the call.

Answer (score 2):

inside of showHourglass() you could do something like this...

```
function showHourglass() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    setTimeout(function() {
         document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }, 5000);

}
```

This will kick off a process to run after 5 seconds to set the cursor back to normal. This assumes that the "cancel" button is the Stop Button of the browser.

Comment: Obviously you would need to tweak the timeout to be a value that works best for you, but it should definitely not take any longer than 5 seconds for your user to be sent to the new resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event to your cancel button that changes your cursor back to `default`.

The onclick attribute:

```
onclick="resetCursor()"
```

Javascript:

```
function resetCursor() {
     document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's a good solution, but they click on the browser's cancel button in a download prompt menu.

Comment: Oooooooh, so THAT's what you're doing. I'd go for El Guapo's solution, then.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind an function to either the cancel event(is it a `click` event?) or the `onload` event in you JS code.

```
$('#cancel_button').click(hideHourglass);
$(document).ready(hideHourglass);

function hideHourglass() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
```